# Send Http Request to Update list item value is not triggering the flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, ms-flow

I am using the `Send HTTP Request to Sharepoint` action to update the metadata values of the SharePoint library item (I am updating the same values which are already there in the item) in the `When a file is created or modified`(Properties only) trigger for the SharePoint library . The flow ran successfuly, but the flow was not triggered.
I have included an image for your reference.

Thanks in advance.

​​​​​​​Scenario:

I am sending an approval process to a person and waiting for 2 days for his response , if he didn't responded within 2 days means i want to cancel that approval and resend it again .

So in case the approval got timeout i am updating the status value to the same existing status value so that the flow will comes to the same condition and send an approval to the respective person.

Is this is the expected behavior, or is there any way to update the same value and trigger the flow

[image]

Comment: why don't you use the Update Item action?

Comment: Hi @jimas13 Will it modify the item, if we update the same value again?

Comment: have you enabled the version history of the list? Can you verify that a new version history item is created once you tun your update?

Comment: i ran a test by updating the same value to a field of a list item and had another flow set to execute on the Updated event. The test ran succesfully. Have you tried running a test?

Comment: Hi @jimas13 I tried Update file Properties and it worked as expected. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Happy to hear about the resolution!